# New to programming. How can I write this Rock, Paper, Scissors code better?

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, rock-paper-scissors

I am practicing w/ Python and wanted to code a simple Rock, Paper, Scissors game w/o any user input. I used a list to hold the values and randomly pulled them with a function. I used the the return value from the first function to print the response in the second function, along with the printed results. What are some alternative methods to achieve this same functionality and make this more efficient. Thank you.

```
# Internal Rock, Paper Scissors Game  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

import random

# List string values for the game

r_p_s = [
    'Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'
]


# Function to return random values from List
def game():
    return random.choice(r_p_s) + " vs. " + random.choice(r_p_s)


result = game()  # Returned Value


# Function to print out the results of the returned value with a response

def response():
    print("Roll: " + "\n" + result)

    if "Scissors vs. Paper" == result or \
       "Paper vs. Scissors" == result:
        print("\nScissors beats Paper")

    elif "Scissors vs. Rock" == result or \
         "Rock vs. Scissors" == result:
        print("\nRock beats Scissors!")

    elif "Rock vs. Paper" == result or \
         "Paper vs. Rock" == result:
        print("\nPaper beats Rock!")

    else:
        print("\nDraw! Roll again.")


response()
```

Answer (score 5):

Despite of very simple and "verbose" initial implementation it has a bunch of issues:

- `r_p_s = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']` is better defined as constant of immutable values
- `result` is accessed within `response()` function body as a global variable.
  Instead, it's better called within the function *on demand*:

  ```
  def response():
      result = game()
      ...
  ```
- instead of arbitrary strings concatenation `... + " vs. " + ...`, `"Roll: " + "\n" + result` 
  - use flexible `f-string` formatting.
  For ex.: `print(f"Roll: \n{result}")`
- the conditions like:

  ```
  if "Scissors vs. Paper" == result or \
      "Paper vs. Scissors" == result:
      print("\nScissors beats Paper")
  ```

  are too verbose and hard-coded to be manageable and reliable

---

Now, when you realize the bad things described above and wonder if there a manageable and advanced approach - take and consider the one below, which is OOP approach representing **`RPSGame`** class (as a main class) and powered by [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) classes to represent the crucial *shapes*.
The new implementation itself is pretty descriptive (I hope). Enjoy!

```
import random
from enum import Enum


class RPSGame:
    class Shape(Enum):
        R = 'Rock'
        P = 'Paper'
        S = 'Scissors'

    # winning outcome bindings
    WIN_OUTCOMES = {
        (Shape.P, Shape.R), (Shape.R, Shape.S), (Shape.S, Shape.P),
    }

    @staticmethod
    def choice():
        shapes = list(RPSGame.Shape)
        return random.choice(shapes), random.choice(shapes)

    def play(self):
        shape1, shape2 = self.choice()
        print(f"Roll: \n{shape1.value} vs {shape2.value}\n")

        if shape1 == shape2:
            print("Draw! Roll again.")
        else:
            # check to swap shapes to get winning output order
            if (shape1, shape2) not in RPSGame.WIN_OUTCOMES:
                shape1, shape2 = shape2, shape1
            print(f"{shape1.value} beats {shape2.value}!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    rps = RPSGame()
    rps.play()
    rps.play()
    rps.play()
```

Sample output (from 3 plays):

```
Roll: 
Paper vs Scissors

Scissors beats Paper!
Roll: 
Scissors vs Scissors

Draw! Roll again.
Roll: 
Rock vs Paper

Paper beats Rock!
```

Comment: I really appreciate the time you took to answer. Im getting my feet wet with classes currently. Quick question, what does @ staticmethod do?

Comment: @Wicked1Kanobi https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod

Comment: I'd definitely advocate for including the full name in the Enum, eg `Shape.Rock` if that's the direction you want to go.

Comment: You have a single method and no state to persist. Why would you want to write a class?

Comment: @409_Conflict, Class is not mandatory as *"something with persistent state"*. As well as specific *Factory* class could have NO state, but just generate a specific instances (with *factory* method). Here, I used classes to show how it could be flexibly organized and structured. And since it's a class now, it can be extended and filled with any needed state.

Comment: Well, this is not Java, if you need a factory, a simple function or a classmethod can do. For now you're complicating things by introducing the need to instantiate in order to call the one stateless method. Removing the class namespace would allow to call `play` directly. And for the possibility to add state... This is rock paper scissors, YAGNI; or at least it shouldn't be this class' responsibility anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with a list like you did:

```
rps = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']
```

What do we notice with the ordering? Each one always beats the previous one: Paper beats Rock, Scissors beats Paper & Rock beats Scissors (when we wrap around).

We can exploit that logic:

```
difference = rps.index(first_shape) - rps.index(second_shape)
```

This difference means we now have a very simple way of determining the winner. If it's zero, it's a tie, otherwise the difference tells us who won, and we'll be using the ability to use negative list indexes:

For a length 3 list: `lst[-1] == lst[2]` and `lst[-2] == lst[1]`.  So a difference of 1 means the first player won, and a difference of 2 means the second player won, and python is gonna handle the negative cases for us automatically. Nice!

So we can just use this directly to figure out who won with the help of a `winner_lookup` list that makes this

```
winner_lookup = ["\nDraw! Roll again!", 
                 f"\n{first_shape} beats {second_shape}!", 
                 f"\n{second_shape} beats {first_shape}!"]
print(winner_lookup[difference])
```

Now we can change the input/output strings without fear of damaging our business logic.

To diverge entirely from using strings for business, let's make our choices as just the index of the choice we want:

```
first_shape, second_shape = random.randint(0, 2), random.randint(0, 2)
```

To take player input, we'd just use `rps.index(player_input)` to get the index of their choice. This also means all the prints need to use `rps[shape]` to get the string instead of the index.

We can pull all of the strings outside of the play function, which all together gives us:

```
import random

rps = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']
match_string = "Roll:\n{} vs {}"
tie_string = "\nDraw! Roll again!"
winner_string = "\n{} beats {}!"

def autoplay():
    first, second = random.randint(0, 2), random.randint(0, 2)
    difference = first - second
    winner_lookup = [tie_string, 
                     winner_string.format(rps[first], rps[second]),
                     winner_string.format(rps[second], rps[first])]
    print(match_string.format(rps[first], rps[second]))
    print(winner_lookup[difference])
```

Where you may want to use classes and objects instead of this is if you wanted to implement RPSLS (Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock), as this implementation relies on the game rules being only *each entry is beaten by the next entry*. But if we wanted to change any of the strings, we don't affect the code at all.